# White Box Appears Over iAdBanner?

Tags: autolayout, iad

I'm trying to implement an `iAdBanner` at the bottom of my application. Everything worked fine the first few times I ran it, and now I see this white box above the `iAdBanner`:

[image]

All I have done in terms of layout has been to put the banner on the blue lines for the left and bottom container margins. I haven't given it any constraints. How can I get rid of this white box?

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. How are you adding the `ADBannerView`, programmatically? Interface Builder? What else is included in this View Controller?

Comment: I added it through interface builder. The only other thing is the info button in the top right. I've been playing around with the program and I realized the problem only occurs when I have given the view controller a background colour (in this case the red).

Comment: Are you also including `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`? I suspect the white box is the `ADBannerView` you've added through Interface Builder, and the `ADBannerView` that is showing correctly is created by `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by centring the `ADBannerView` horizontally and giving it a vertical spacing of 0 from the Bottom Layout Guide. Just placing it on the left container margin and bottom layout guide is not enough. Let `iAd` handle the width and height.